# How do I get the size requirement for my condenser?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, thermodynamics

I'm planning to build a desalination machine and I want to know at what size the condenser should be.

What I did first was that I did a first law analysis of a heat exchanger, with incoming seawater as the cooling fluid:

$$0 = \dot m_{coolingliquid}h_{coolingliquid} - \dot m_{vapor}h_{condensation} + \dot Q_{sl}$$

**First of all**, Is my calculation/understanding correct?

**second**, How can I get the mass flow rates of both my cooling fluid and vapor?

**Also**, How do I find the size of my heat exchanger?

Answer (score 0):

Define the mass flow of the vapor and the temperature.

Then define the delta-T of the cooling fluid and guess the mass flow rate and area

Iterate a few times, perhaps the size has a max limit etc.